# Scaling :hover effect isn't working in css on <p>

Tags: html, css

Short and simple, I'm trying to use a hover effect, and I can't seem to get it to work within this DIV at the moment and I've never came across this problem and I can't find out where I went wrong.

```css
.navbar {
      border: solid 0px; background-color: #E6E6E6; padding-top: 15px; padding-
      bottom: 15px;
      position: absolute; top: 230px; left: 320px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      }
     .shopping,
     .food,
     .hotels,
     .entertainment,
     .guide {
      display: inline;
      padding-right: 90px;
      padding-left: 90px;
      }
      .shopping:hover,
      .food:hover,
      .hotels:hover,
      .entertainment:hover,
      .guide:hover {
       color: yellow;
       -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
       -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
       transform: scale(1.3);
       }
```

```html
 <div class="navbar">
      <p class="shopping"><a href="shopping.html">Shopping</a></p>
      <p class="food"><a href="food.html">Food</p>
      <p class="hotels"><a href="hotels.html">Hotels</p>
      <p class="entertainment"><a href="entertainment.html">Entertainment</p>
      <p class="guide"><a href="guide.html">The total NOLA guide.</p>
     </div>
```

The weird part is that the color yellow ends up being shown but the hover that I want the scaling portion is not working and I can't figure it out.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Scale the container, or scale the container contents. If you want to scale the contents, then you have to target the content - not the container. The container will scale automatically to fit the content so long as you don't define a fixed height and width on the container.

Comment: I'm trying to get the contents of <P> to scale. shopping, food, etc.

Comment: How's my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code  to this.It will target the anchor tag inside the p tag.And add `display:inline-block` to the anchor tag for the scale to work

```
    .shopping:hover a,
      .food:hover a,
      .hotels:hover a,
      .entertainment:hover a,
      .guide:hover a{
       color: yellow;
       -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
       -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
       transform: scale(1.3);
    }
```

```css
.navbar {
      border: solid 0px; background-color: #E6E6E6; padding-top: 15px; padding-
      bottom: 15px;
      position: absolute; top: 230px; left: 320px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      }
     .shopping,
     .food,
     .hotels,
     .entertainment,
     .guide {
      display: inline-block;
      padding-right: 90px;
      padding-left: 90px;
      }
      .shopping:hover a,
      .food:hover a,
      .hotels:hover a,
      .entertainment:hover a,
      .guide:hover a{
       color: yellow;
       -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
       -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
       transform: scale(1.3);
       }
       
       .shopping a,
      .food a,
      .hotels a,
      .entertainment a,
      .guide a{
       background:red;
       display: inline-block; 
      }
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
      <p class="shopping"><a href="shopping.html">Shopping</a></p>
      <p class="food"><a href="food.html">Food</p>
      <p class="hotels"><a href="hotels.html">Hotels</p>
      <p class="entertainment"><a href="entertainment.html">Entertainment</p>
      <p class="guide"><a href="guide.html">The total NOLA guide.</p>
     </div>
```

Comment: Sadly it was targeting fine, but it's the scaling portion of the CSS that isn't working still

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is wrong. You can use `font-size:` to achive the same goal.

```css
p:hover {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Shopping</p>
```

Using `scale` on HTML text messes things up sometimes, and it's best not to use it for text.

Using your code, this would be:

```css
.navbar {
  border: solid 0px;
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 230px;
  left: 320px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.shopping, .food, .hotels, .entertainment, .guide {
  padding-right: 90px;
  padding-left: 90px;
  height: 20px;
}
.grow:hover > a {
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="shopping grow"><a href="shopping.html">Shopping</a></div>
    <div class="food grow"><a href="food.html">Food</a></div>
    <div class="hotels grow"><a href="hotels.html">Hotels</a></div>
    <div class="entertainment grow"><a href="entertainment.html">Entertainment</a></div>
    <div class="guide grow"><a href="guide.html">The total NOLA guide.</a></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would switch the nesting to have the `<a>` tag on the outer, and then inner use a `<span>` tag.

```css
a.f > span { 
  font-size: 1em;
  color: grey;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

a.f > span:hover { 
    font-size: 22em;
    color: brown;
}
```

```html
<a href="food.html" class="f"><span class="f">Food</span></a>
```